# Django Custom Client Login Page not Authenticating

Tags: python, django, authentication

New to Django and came from Laravel where it was much easier to setup login and authentication. That is to say I am struggling getting a simple login page to work properly and have spent several nights working on it using SO, Django docs, and various tutorials. The Django documentation doesn't seem to be organized well for someone just trying to get the basics of login page, kind of overwhelming, and most of the SO answers are old that I have come across.

These two tutorials I have used and neither gets me what I am after:

[Right way of adding user authentication to Django](http://blog.narenarya.in/right-way-django-authentication.html)

[How to Use Django's Built-in Login System](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html)

Using Python 3.5.2, Django 1.10, and PostgreSQL 9.6. In my setup, `localhost:8000` is the login page. The user needs to login before they can view anything. I also have apps `/home`, `/results`, etc. but right now I am only working with `/home`. If they try to go to `localhost:8000/home` they will be routed to login doing this currently brings them to `http://localhost:8000/?next=/home/`. So that much is working good.

When I enter credentials, it just keeps sending me to the login screen. Going to `localhost:8000` or `/home` just does the same thing. Doesn't seem like it is authenticating. DB credentials are correct, user credentials are correct and communicating with the database in `python manage.py shell` is fine.

Here is my simplified directory structure:

```
~/portal-client

project_dir
    apps
        account
            templates
                account
                    login.html
            forms.py
            urls.py
            views.py
        home
            templates
                home
                    home.html
            urls.py
            views.py
        results
    settings.py
    urls.py
scripts
    manage.py
static
templates
    base.html
    footer.html
    title.html
```

**project_dir/settings.py**

```
# INSTALLED_APPS, TEMPLATES, STATIC, DATABASES all correct so just this line added
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

**project_dir/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from account.forms import LoginForm

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include('account.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^documents/$', include('documents.urls')),
    url(r'^help/$', include('help.urls')),
    url(r'^home/$', include('home.urls')),
    url(r'^results/$', include('results.urls')),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'account/login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name='login'),
]
```

**home/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your view here.
# The following prohibits access to the website unless authenticated
@login_required(login_url="/")
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home/home.html')
```

**account/urls.py - EDIT**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
]
```

**account/forms.py - EDIT**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django import forms

# If you don't do this you cannot use Bootstrap CSS
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm:
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
    def clean_password(self):
        password= self.cleaned_data.get("password")
```

**account/views.py - EDIT**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import views
from .forms import LoginForm

# Create your view here.
def user_login(request):

    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
           login(request, user)
           return httpResponseRedirect('/home')
        else:
           return httpResponseRedirect('/')
    context = {
    "form" : form
     }
    return render(request, "account/login.html", context)
```

**account/login.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'home' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">

            {{ form.username }}

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>


        <div class="col-md-6">

            {{ form.password }}

        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Login
            </button>

            <a class="btn btn-link" href="url('/password/reset')">
                Forgot Your Password?
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

I think that is everything! I appreciate the help in advance! Would love to get on with putting these apps together and get past the authentication.

**EDIT:**

One thing I haven't read though is if I need to do anything with `account/models.py` file. All the customer data is in in the default `auth_user` table.

Also, wondering if something like [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) might be a good solution.

Comment: django-allauth supports registration, and log in with other providers e.g. Google. If you only want a login view, then you don't need it - Django already has a login view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django comes with [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views), you should use these if possible instead of writing your own.

You already included the built-in login view in your URL patterns.

```
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'account/login.html'}, name='login'),
```

Therefore you don't need your `user_login` view, so I would remove it. I have removed your custom authentication form because it is not required. The default authentication form already has the username and password fields. You have broken the `clean_` methods because you don't return a value.

Next, fix the form's `action` in your template. Currently you are submitting the form data to the `home` view. You should send it to the `login` view.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
```

Finally, I would add `LOGIN_URL = 'login'` to your settings, then you can simplify the code that uses `login_required` to the following:

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    ...
```

Comment: I would definitely like to use the built in views and forms, but have been trying to follow these tutorials to no avail. Finding the Django documentation unclear, but I will read through again what you posted. Anyway, I made the change you proposed and logging in still just keeps going to the login screen and not advancing to `/home`.

Comment: Ok, read through the documentation and still having the same issue. I did modify my code though.

Comment: Well, that is terribly easy! Thanks for giving me a hand, it is working now! The tutorials I was using had me all screwed up and overthinking the problem... and I'm a noob.